# if and else on jquery

Tags: jquery

I need some help here with if else.

I'm not sure how I can do it.

I'm using several  tags and it works, but I know it can be improved, by using if and else.

But i'm not able to figure out where and how to do it. I've tried without sucess.

Any ideas on how it can be ???

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#but-1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "extra/pageB.html", success: function (result) {
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#but-2").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "extra/pageC.html", success: function (result) {
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#but-3").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "extra/pageD.html", success: function (result) {
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean if/else logic? The question is a bit unclear to me

Comment: Sorry, I just rewrote the question. Instead of using several <script> tags I want to use if and else to only use one tag.

Comment: you can remove the script tags and put everything in the same document ready call

Comment: This question remain unclear, what are you trying to achieve ? Why do you want to use if/else ?

Comment: Hello, Bruno, did you check my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it in 1 function.

```
<button id="but-1" class="btn-action" data-href="extra/pageB.html">Button1</button>
<button id="but-2" class="btn-action" data-href="extra/pageC.html">Button2</button>
<button id="but-3" class="btn-action" data-href="extra/pageD.html">Button3</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-action").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).data("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: url, 
            success: function (result) {
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```